# How to use pipeline from transformers, summarization? Python

Tags: python, pipeline, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

I am trying to use pipeline from transformers to summarize the text. But what I can get is only truncated text from original one.
My code is:

```
from transformers import pipeline
summarizer = pipeline("summarization")
summarizer("The present invention discloses a pharmaceutical composition comprising therapeutically effective amount of, or an extract consisting essentially therapeutically effective amount of at least one cannabinoid selected from the group consisting of: Cannabidiol (CBD) or a derivative thereof, Tetrahydrocannabinol (THC) or a derivative thereof, and any combination thereof, for use in the treatment of multiple myeloma (MM). The present invention further discloses methods and uses of the aforementioned composition.", 
       min_length=5, max_length=10)
```

The output is

```
[{'summary_text': ' The present invention discloses a pharmaceutical'}]
```

That is just a beginning of the text for analysis. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing, this is just the conclusion your model made. You have to play around with different models and parameters to find something that suits your corpus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gave as an argument max_length=10, meaning that the maximum length of the generated text should be no longer than 10 tokens. By increasing this number, the generated summaries will get longer.

Comment: my target is opposite.. probably you can suggest me some other model for my purpose - very short summarization of text?

Comment: I don't think there are currently any reasonable choices out there for your purposes. Other than training your own model on top of checkpoints I'd say you are unfortunately out of luck...